# Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-deployment, testing

I am getting the error `Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function` for the constructor of my contract and no idea why.

I just upgraded to `Truffle 4.0.0 beta` and using the `truffle develop` test environment instead of `testrpc`. These tests used to pass, but now they are giving me errors.

**Contract constructor**

```
function MyContract(
        bytes _eventName, 
        bytes32[] _eventResultNames, 
        uint256 _eventBettingEndBlock,
        uint256 _decisionEndBlock,
        uint8 _averageBlockTime,
        uint256 _arbitrationOptionMinutes) 
        public
        payable
    {
        ...
    }
```

**Mocha test class**

```
const params = {
        _eventName: "test",
        _eventResultNames: ["first", "second", "third"],
        _eventBettingEndBlock: 100,
        _decisionEndBlock: 120,
        _averageBlockTime: 10,
        _arbitrationOptionMinutes: 1440
    };
const baseReward = Utils.getBigNumberWithDecimals(10, nativeDecimals);

let myContract;

beforeEach(async function() {
        myContract = await MyContract.new(...Object.values(params), { from: creator, value: baseReward });
    });
```

**Error message**

```
1) Contract: MyContract New MyContract inits the MyContract with the correct values:
     Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
      at Object.InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:43993:16)
      at SolidityFunction.validateArgs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:357969:22)
      at SolidityFunction.toPayload (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:357985:10)
      at SolidityFunction.call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:358026:24)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:326504:16
      at Promise (<anonymous>)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:326495:18
      at <anonymous>
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your build folder, then run the command. The reset command might work for some, didn't for me, might be a Mac thing.

`npm run truffle migrate --reset --compile-all`

I find it works best when running truffle locally to the folder rather than globally, due to the beta and different versions getting updated quickly recently.
if you prefer the global approach try

`truffle migrate --reset --compile-all`

Comment: Ya I figured this out eventually as well. I don't think the `--compile-all` actually recompiles it lol.

Answer (score 2):

Hello from the future and the past!

If you are in the sample project of Hardhat and have customized your Greeter.sol contract [perhaps to deploy an ERC-721 contract] and are now trying to run sample-script.js and it is now failing with

> reason: 'too many arguments:  in Contract constructor'

Go into /sample-script.js to

```
  const greeter = await Greeter.deploy("Hello, Hardhat!");
```

and remove the argument as so:

```
  const greeter = await Greeter.deploy();
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue yesterday. It seems to be a bug in the Truffle 4.0.0 beta.
I rollback to the latest stable version **3.4.11** and it fixed the issue.

```
npm uninstall -g truffle

npm install -g truffle
```

**EDIT:** The project needs to be rebuilt/redeployed:

```
truffle migrate --reset --compile-all
```

Comment: I have actually already tried rolling back, but my tests still don't pass. Did you do anything special other than those two commands?

Comment: I just rerun the migration with the parameter reset and compile-all: `truffle migrate --reset --compile-all` . I think the JSON build file has to be regenerated.

Comment: `truffle migrate --reset --compile-all` worked! Thank you! For some reason, calling `truffle compile -all` then `truffle migrate --reset` didn't fix it...

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately the above suggested answer didn't work. Try deleting the build folder and then compile deploy

`truffle migrate --reset`

I had the same issue, the compiled code is corrupted. It works for the first time only and the subsequent compile corrupts the build. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting the build folder and run

`truffle migrate --reset`

I had the same issue, the compiled code was corrupted. Hope this helps.